# How to join two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, full-outer-join

I have an `income` table that looks like this:

```
date              income      
---------------------------
09/05/13          56000    
09/05/13          66600
09/05/13          50000
```

And an `expense` table that looks like this:

```
date              expense 
----------------------------
09/05/13          68800
```

I want to write a query whose output looks like this:

```
date              income             expense 
---------------------------------------------
09/05/13          56000              68800
09/05/13          66600
09/05/13          50000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** If you're not concerned with particular order in which income values are matched to expense values you can get your desired output with a query like this

```
SELECT date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount END) income,
       MAX(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amount END) expense
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 type, date, income amount, @n := IF(@g = date, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := date g
    FROM income CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, date, expense amount, @m := IF(@f = date, @m + 1, 1) rnum, @f := date g
    FROM expense CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m := 0, @f := NULL) i2
) q
 GROUP BY date, rnum
```

Output:

```
|               DATE | INCOME | EXPENSE |
|--------------------|--------|---------|
| September, 05 2013 |  56000 |   68800 |
| September, 05 2013 |  66600 |  (null) |
| September, 05 2013 |  50000 |  (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280dd/10)** demo

---

**UPDATE1:** It seems logical to group incomes and expenses per day with a query like

```
SELECT a.date, i.income, e.expense
  FROM
(
  SELECT date
    FROM income
  UNION
  SELECT date
    FROM expense 
) a LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT date, SUM(income) income
    FROM income
   GROUP BY date
) i
    ON a.date = i.date LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT date, SUM(expense) expense
    FROM expense
   GROUP BY date
) e
    ON a.date = e.date
```

Output:

```
|               DATE | INCOME | EXPENSE |
|--------------------|--------|---------|
| September, 05 2013 | 172600 |   68800 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280dd/4)** demo

---

**Original answer to original question:** If you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (over `date` column) as you stated in your original question then this will do it

```
SELECT a.date, i.income, e.expense
  FROM
(
  SELECT date
    FROM income
  UNION
  SELECT date
    FROM expense 
) a LEFT JOIN income i
    ON a.date = i.date LEFT JOIN expense e
    ON a.date = e.date
```

But then you will get this as output

```
|          DATE | INCOME | EXPENSE |
|---------------|--------|---------|
| September, 05 |  56000 |   68800 |
| September, 05 |  66600 |   68800 |
| September, 05 |  50000 |   68800 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280dd/1)** demo

Comment: getting duplicate entry in expense

Comment: @FaztrickFazilPv That's because you asked for full outer join. What is the deterministic rule to decide with which of income rows to show your one expense row and vice versa?

Comment: @FaztrickFazilPv Then it's not full outer join and you need to answer the question in prev comment to fix the query.

Comment: which join to use this situation

Comment: How about to group incomes and expenses per day? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280dd/4

Comment: no that not possible because it was a report (and its a sample tbl)

Comment: OK, then back to the question. What is deterministic rule that says which rows from income table show with which rows from expenses? When you formulate the answer we can immediately fix the query.

Comment: @FaztrickFazilPv See updated answer for a solution. Let me know if works for you